# How to prevent duplicate records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's probably trivial question but i can't find any solutions to make this right.

```
def make_thing
  @thing = Thing.new

  if @thing.save
    redirect_to some_path
  end
end

<%= link_to "Make Thing", controller: :things, action: :make_thing %>
```

Sending multiple requests(by pressing "Make Thing" link) to "make_thing" action will multiple call save method before it would be redirected. So this will create multiple records.
How can i record only single "thing" and redirect then?

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `disable_with` ([Rails 4: Disable submit button after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812230/rails-4-disable-submit-button-after-click)) and check uniqueness of the record at `model-` or `database-level`.

UPD:

You can do something like this for disabling with image (slim):

`= link_to "#", data: { disable_with: "<span class='with_image' class='with_image'>Submitting...</span>" }
  span
    | Submit`

And css:

`.with_image {
  background: url('/assets/test.jpg');
}`

But it is better to use jquery loader or something like that...
Hope I helped with my answer.

Comment: is it possible to use an image as value for disable_with?